# .mdb file completely corrupt after the frequent recoveries

Tags: database, microsoft-access

I am running Access database and one of .mdb files was corrupted for a long time. I got an error messages repeatedly, unfortunately I don’t remember exactly which ones. I let it go because I was still able to recover it, even partially, through the Compact and repair and /decompile. Also through a copy of the necessary parts of the file. Not so bad.

Recently I got the next error: `"The database .mdb can't be repaired or isn't a Microsoft Access database file"`. This time no fix is working. Probably the file definitely corrupt.

Can I recover it somehow? I have a backup, but it is too old and if it possible I wouldn’t use it.

I was careless in this

Comment: It sounds like the file is beyond repair based on the description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no. You can't even recover the database partially because it is not even recognized by Microsoft Access. Some options:

- You can try a third party software to attempt a recovery of the file
- Use a free software such as [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) to recover the file that delete
- Use your old backup and reconstruct from there.